# EL autocomplete doesn't work for <h:dataTable var>

Tags: jsf, netbeans, intellisense, el

EL autocomplete doesn't work for `<h:dataTable var>` in Netbeans. I'd expect to see properties of `#{oi}`, not to see global variables.

See below screenshot:

![enter image description here][1]

How can I get it to work in Netbeans?

Comment: This is a question about your IDE. You should tell which one it is, and tag your question accordingly. That said, I don't see how any IDE could know what to suggest, since it doesn't know the type of `o1` in your example.

Comment: Actually, if there is a bean named `Filmsbean` with a setter named `getList()`, maybe an IDE would be able to check if that is a typed list. Have no idea if Netbeans can do that, though...